# HTTP Webserver ignoring last line of POST request

Tags: java, http, webserver

I'm trying to create a simple web server in java just to learn how HTTP works. Everything is going well except the fact that the last line of a POST request never reaches the server.

That's my Java client thread handler:

```
BufferedReader os = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
HTTPRequest http = null;
String v;
while((v = os.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(v);
    if(http == null && !v.isEmpty()) {
        http = new HTTPRequest(v);
    }else if(v == "" || v == null || v.isEmpty()){
        http.setReady();
    }else if(!http.ready()){
        http.addHeaders(v);
    }else {
        http.appendData(v);
    }
    
    if((http.getMethod() != HTTPMethod.POST && http.ready()) 
            || (http.getData() != null && http.hasHeader("Content-Length") 
            && String.valueOf(http.getData().length()) == http.getHeader("Content-Length"))) {
        DispatchHttpRequest(http, socket, bw);
        break;
    }
}
```

That's how i'm calling the POST request:

```
var data = null;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
    }
});

xhr.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8888/");
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/javascript");
xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");

xhr.send(JSON.stringify({error:[],status:200,data:"teste"},null,4));
```

And that's the what I get in console:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 59
cache-control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.75 Safari/537.36
content-type: application/javascript
Accept: */*                                       
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8888
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8888/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7

{
    "error": [],
    "status": 200,
    "data": "teste"
```

As you can see the } is missing, I didn't find anyone with this issue. :(